# Populate SharedPreferences in RecyclerView

Tags: android

So I'm trying to populate the aac files with `value=true` from my SharedPreferences in my RecyclerView that is inside the fragment.

here is how my sharedpreferences looks like.

```
<map>
    <boolean name="/storage/emulated/0/Download/VoiceRecorder/cute naman.aac" value="true" />
    <boolean name="/storage/emulated/0/Download/VoiceRecorder/AudioRecording.aac" value="false" />
</map>
```

Then in my HeadsetFragment.java

```
private void updateFavoriteIcon() {
    if (isFavorite) {
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.favorite);
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.not_favorite);
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Not Favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        fileList = getAACFiles();
        filesAdapter = new FilesAdapter(fileList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(filesAdapter);
    }
}

private List<FileItem> getAACFiles() {
    List<FileItem> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
    File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath() + "/VoiceRecorder");
    if (directory.exists() && directory.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".aac")) {
                    FileItem fileItem = new FileItem();
                    fileItem.setFile(file);
                    fileItem.setCreationDate(getFormattedCreationDate(file.lastModified()));

                    // Calculate file size
                    fileItem.setFileSize(file.length());

                    // Calculate audio length
                    String audioLength = getAudioLength(file);
                    fileItem.setAudioLength(audioLength);

                    fileList.add(fileItem);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

in my else statement I was able to populate all the aac files from the `directory`.

Since I'm not familiar with SharedPreferences I don't know if its possible to populate the files with `value="true"` in my recyclerview.